# How do I write a method that takes in a generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics, stack

in my java project I am using two stacks, one that holds only doubles, and another one that holds integers.

Now I would like to write a generic method `putToStack(element)` that takes an element, which is either a double or an integer, and puts it to the according stack.

My problem is that I still have some problems with the generic syntax. Basically I would like to have this method (please correct it!) Can someone help me with the Java implementation?

```
public void putToStack(Generic parameter) {
    if (isDouble(parameter)) {
        doubleStack.put(parameter);
    } else {
        integerStack.put(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use method overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point to making the method generic if you need to extract the type later anyway.  Use overloaded methods, each taking the type you need.

```
public void putToStack(double parameter) {
    doubleStack.put(parameter);
}
public void putToStack(int parameter) {
    integerStack.put(parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Object` as the parmeter as it is the parent class of all the classes and hence can hold the object of any subclass:

```
public void putToStack(Object parameter)
```

**Note:** But think about your design more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need generics, what you're looking for is simple polymorphism.

java.lang.Number is the base class of both Integer and Double, so it's the most appropriate. However think about what happens when someone tries to add a Float to your method?

In this case you want to overload the method so that only double and int are allowed. This way you avoid that case and even remove that ugly if statement.

```
public void putToStack(Double number) {
    doubleStack.put(parameter);
}
public void putToStack(Integer number) {
    integerStack.put(parameter);
}
```

Comment: But what if the method `putToStack` becomes longer (e.g check if the stack is empty or not) than just one line of code. Wouldn't that be a lot of repetitive code??

Comment: That's a different scenario and now it makes more sense to use what I said about java.langa.Number. Also don't use Object like Juned Ahsan recommended since it's too general.